# Fixed "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" line, but still getting the error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am attempting to run the haxby_decoding example from [Neumapper](https://braindynamicslab.github.io/neumapper/). The code runs well on my personal computer, but when I attempt to run it on my work computer, I get this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dyneusr/core.py", line 50, in __init__
> self.fit(**params)
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dyneusr/core.py", line 106, in fit
> A, M, TCM = tools.extract_matrices(G, index=data_ids)
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dyneusr/tools/graph_utils.py", line 431, in extract_matrices
> node_members = np.array(list(node_to_members.values()))
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (966,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I have gone through the code manually in the terminal and found that I can get the `node_members` variable to run correctly and match the variable generated on my personal computer by using,

```
node_members = np.array(list(node_to_members.values()), dtype=object)
```

But after altering this line in the `graph_utils.py` file,  I am still getting the same error.

```
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dyneusr/tools/graph_utils.py", line 431, in extract_matrices
> node_members = np.array(list(node_to_members.values()), dtype=object)
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (966,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Comment: What is `node_to_members.values()`?  I'm not sure the `list()` is needed, but in any case, it contains lists or arrays that vary in size, which is why you get the error, or have to specify `object` dtype.

Comment: Is `dyneusr` your own code, or some package that you are using?  The `self.fit` line suggests this is doing some sort of numerical `fit` calculation.  In that case the input needs to numeric, float, dtype, not "ragged" object dtype.  So the problem might not be in this code, but in the values that you pass to `fit`.  Do you understand what we mean by "ragged" data, or data that varies in size?

Comment: @hpaulj 'dyneusr' is a package used by 'neumapper'.  Thank you for editing my post. Yes, I know what you mean by "ragged" and my data didn't vary in size when I looked at it directly. I don't know why but when I closed python in the terminal and tried running the code again with my edit, it worked.